# Fetch url from html code with python and selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, pdf

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146690/get-links-of-dropdown-menu-in-each-row-of-the-table-with-python3-and-selenium) I was helped to address a dropdown menu in a table. However, I wish to fetch the url from the source code which is:

`<a href="#" onclick="window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&amp;rdd=nYgT5Rcvs2I%3D');return false;">PDF</a>`

and store it in a list, instead of clicking on it as it is currently done. The link in the above code is `/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=nYgT5Rcvs2I%3D`. However, I would need to add before each fetched link `http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni` to complete the link.

How can I achieve that?

This is my current script and this the website http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# A small script to download issues of the Gaceta de Nicaragua (1843-1960) 19758 issues

import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

import os
import sys
import time
import shutil
import urllib
from subprocess import call
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() # profile to prevent download manager
profile.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 0) # accept all cookies
profile.set_preference("network.cookie.lifetimePolicy", 0) # accept cookies
profile.set_preference("network.cookie.alwaysAcceptSessionCookies", 1) # always allow sess
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1) # open tabs in same window
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'Downloads/')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'image/jpeg;application/jpeg;image/jpg;application/jpg')

url = 'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/' # web page
print('Opening digesto.asamblea.gob.ni...')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url) # open url

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cavanzada"]').click() # advanced menu
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='slcCollection']/option[text()='Diario Oficial']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='slcMedio']/option[text()='Gaceta Oficial']").click() # change journal name here

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDatePublishFrom"]')
inputElement.send_keys('01/01/1844') # change start date

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDatePublishTo"]')
inputElement.send_keys('31/12/1860') # change end date

time.sleep( 5 ) # wait for Human Captcha Insertion

inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # search

time.sleep( 2 ) # wait to load

select_element = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="slcResPage"]')) # page count
select_element.select_by_value('50') # max 50

time.sleep( 1 ) # wait to load

table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tableDocCollection')
rows = table_id.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody tr") # get all table rows
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('li a[onclick*=pdf]').click() # .get_attribute("href")
    list_of_links = driver.current_url
    driver.close() # quit() #close window
    print(list_of_links)
```

**Disclaimer:** when using the script you need to type the captcha by hand without pressing enter for the script to continue.

Comment: I'd recommend in the future to add only the relevant parts of the code - the full listing did help me to repeat it (manually), but the sheer length of it probably turned off a lot of folks from actually reading it. I'm speaking out of personal experience - too often I don't bother reading the full question, if it doesn't grab me immediately and there are two pages of code I have to skim through. E.g. a recommendation IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative links starting off with `/` are from the top-level domain, e.g. `http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni` in your case; on the other hand, if they don't start with that, they are from the current page. Inside the loop where you're scraping the links, change the code to this:

```
list_of_links = []    # will hold the scraped links
tld = 'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni'
current_url = driver.current_url   # for any links not starting with /
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
    link = row.find_element_by_css_selector('li a[onclick*=pdf]').get_attribute("href")
    if link.startswith('/'):
        list_of_links.append(tld + link)
    else:
        list_of_links.append(current_url + link)

    # at this point the dropdown will be visible, and will interfere with the next loop cycle
    # click again in it, so the menu closes
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()

print(list_of_links)
```

Comment: Thank you, Todor, for your recommendation and answer. Regarding the first, it did not do it intentionally but thought that it might be better to answer the question. I will next time add less code. I have tried your code and get an error message `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"> is not clickable at point (1199.658317565918,270.18333435058594) because another element <a href="#"> obscures it`.

Comment: I've realized what is the issue - after the dropdown with the link is expanded, it stays like this; then in the next cycle selenium cannot click the button on the next row - the dropdown is in the way. The "fix" I'm thinking of is to once again click the button - this will probably hide the dropdown (I can't check myself, typing on mobile). If that doesn't do it, find some other place/locator to click, so that dropdown hides at the end of every cycle.

Comment: Thank you Todor, that fixed my issue.