# Trim links in list with python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little script in python3.7 (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154527/fetch-url-from-html-code-with-python-and-selenium/54157476?noredirect=1#comment95154822_54157476)) that scrapes links from a website (http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/) and saves them in a list. Unfortunately, they are only partial and I have to trim them to use them as links.

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
list_of_links = []    # will hold the scraped links
tld = 'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni'
current_url = driver.current_url   # for any links not starting with /
table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tableDocCollection')
rows = table_id.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody tr") # get all table rows
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()
    link = row.find_element_by_css_selector('li a[onclick*=pdf]').get_attribute("onclick") # href
    print(list_of_links)# trim
    if link.startswith('/'):
        list_of_links.append(tld + link)
    else:
        list_of_links.append(current_url + link)
    row.find_element_by_css_selector('button').click()

print(list_of_links)
```

How can I manipulate the list (as an example only with three entries here) that this

```
["http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D');return false;", "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=Z%2FgLeZxynkg%3D');return false;", "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=9rka%2BmYwvYM%3D');return false;"]
```

looks like

```
["http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D", "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=Z%2FgLeZxynkg%3D", "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=9rka%2BmYwvYM%3D"]
```

Breaking it down: on the example of the first link, I get this link from the website basically as

`http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D');return false;`

and need to trim it to

`http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D`.

How do I achieve this in python from the entire list?

Comment: `.replace("/consultas/coleccion/window.open('", "")` will get you started

Comment: What assumtpions can you make? For example do all your links finish with 3D? Do all of them have for example `window.open`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to `split` on the string `/consultas/coleccion/window.open('`, remove the unwanted end of the second string and concatenate the two processed strings to get your result.

This should do it:

```
new_links = []

for link in list_of_links:

    current_strings = link.split("/consultas/coleccion/window.open('")
    current_strings[1] = current_strings[1].split("');return")[0]
    new_link = current_strings[0] + current_strings[1]
    new_links.append(new_link)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
s = "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D');return false;"
s = s.replace("/consultas/coleccion/window.open('", "").replace("');return false;", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, to split the URLs in your list and let `urllib.parse.urljoin()` make the rest for you:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

PATTERN = r"^([\S]+)window.open\('([\S]+)'"

links = ["http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D');return false;"]
result = "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D"

for link in links:
    m = re.match(PATTERN, link, re.MULTILINE).groups()
    #  m is now: ('http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/', '/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D')
    if len(m) == 2:
        newLink = urljoin(*m)
        print(newLink)
        assert newLink == result
```

Returns:

```
http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D
```

Answer (score 1):

To that you can use regular expression:

Consider this code:

```
import re
out = list()
lst = ["http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=p2%2FHzlqau8A%3D');return false;", "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=Z%2FgLeZxynkg%3D');return false;", "http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/window.open('/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=9rka%2BmYwvYM%3D');return false;"]

for el in lst:
    temp = re.sub(r"(.*?)/window.open\('(.*?)'\).*", r"\1\2", el)
    out.append(temp)
    print(temp)
```

The function `sub` allows to replace part of strings matching the pattern specified. Basically it is telling:

- `(.*?)`: keeps all the characters before `/window.open...`
- `/window.open\(` the input string must have the pattern `/window.open(` but it will not be kept
- `(.*?)` keep all characters after the previous pattern until a `)` is found (represented by `\(`)